Repetition in Structural Replace in PhpStorm
I'm working on quite old project and I would like to do some small refactoring.
I have an if statement with condition like
if ($a == 1 || $a == 2 || b == 3)

and I want to replace it (or better write an inspection) with
if (in_array($a, [1, 2, 3]))

I'm able to write Structural replace for exact number of comparison
if ($VAR$ == $VALUE1$ || $VAR$ == $VALUE2$)

but is there a possibility to somehow involve repetion in the process? Sometimes there is one || operator, sometimes there are three or more...
The only solution which come to my mind is to make more intentions each for different number of operators. But I believe there is a better solution than that.

Try rolling up recursively. The idea would be to incrementally move a VALUE into the in_array call:
in_array($a, [1]) || $a == 2 || $a == 4
in_array($a, [1, 2]) || $a == 3 || $a == 4
in_array($a, [1, 2, 3]) || $a == 4
in_array($a, [1, 2, 3, 4])

So the search template would be:
in_array($a$, [$vals$]) || $a$ === $val$

(where Count for $vals$ = [0, Unlimited])
The replace template:
in_array($a$, [$vals$, $val$])

(You'll still have to write a search template for the base case)
Now, in the replace pane, repeatedly press Rerun (Ctrl+F5) and Replace All.

Wow, nice idea, thank you. I ended up with multiple templates for one Inspection... Like $VAR$ == $V1$ || $VAR == $V2$ ... $VAR == $V10$ => in_array($VAR$ [$V1$ ... $V10$]).. An then second template up to $V9$ an so on... It replaces in one step, but it's limited... Your solution keeps me run it again and again, but it is more dynamic...
